# Puzzled by output of Regular Expression Replacement

Tags: c#, regex

I've been trying to understand the output of a Regex.Replace call and I am puzzled as to its output.

I have a Dictionary<string, string>.  I want to search for the keys in the input string and replace them with the corresponding value if the string exists at the beginning of the string, at the end of the string, or in the middle of the string if it is surrounded by one or more spaces on each side.

My input string is as follows:

```
North S West N East W South E W S N West South
```

The regular expression in this code comes out as:

```
(^| +?)SOUTH($| +?)|(^| +?)NORTH($| +?)|(^| +?)EAST($| +?)|(^| +?)WEST($| +?)|(^| +?)E($| +?)|(^| +?)W($| +?)|(^| +?)N($| +?)|(^| +?)S($| +?)
```

My *expected* output is:

```
N SOUTH W NORTH E WEST S EAST WEST SOUTH NORTH W S
```

My *actual* output is:

```
N S W N E W S E WEST S NORTH WEST S
```

The code is below.  The RegEx pattern is constructed from the keys of the dictionary.  I feel I am just misunderstanding something simple about regular expressions.  Why does it pick up *some* of the words but not all of them?  For example, why does it not match the word West near the end of the string, but *does* match the word West near the beginning of the string?  I have added code to write each of the matches and the pattern string but I am stumped.

```
void Main()
{
        var directions = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {"SOUTH", "S"},
            {"NORTH", "N"},
            {"EAST", "E"},
            {"WEST", "W"},
            {"E", "EAST"},
            {"W", "WEST"},
            {"N", "NORTH"},
            {"S", "SOUTH"},
        };

        string input = @"North S West N East W South E W S N West South";

        Console.WriteLine(doReplace(input, directions));
}

private string doReplace(string input, Dictionary<string, string> lookup)
{
    string output = null;

    //Construct the regular expression pattern
    string searchPattern = string.Join(@"|", lookup.Select(s => @"(^| +?)" + s.Key + @"($| +?)").ToArray());
    Console.WriteLine(searchPattern);

    //Perform the replace
    output = Regex.Replace(input.ToUpper(), searchPattern, new MatchEvaluator(m =>
    {
        //Write out each match found
        Console.WriteLine("[{0}]", m.Value);

        string tmp = m.Value.Trim();
        string result = tmp;
        lookup.TryGetValue(tmp, out result);

        //This return statement is for the lambda not the method.
        return m.Value.Replace(tmp, result);
    }), RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture|RegexOptions.Singleline);

    return output;
}
```

Comment: @user2864740 - The actual regular expression is constructed in the code and is output using Console.WriteLine, but I have updated the question with the value.

Comment: @user2864740 - I don't know what more you want.  I posted the regular epxression, the input, the expected output, and the actual output.  I also posted a short but complete program that produces the same.  Please let me know what more I can provide.

Comment: What happens when using: `@"(?:^|\s*)SOUTH|NORTH|EAST|WEST|E|W|N|S(?:$|\s*)"` as the regular expression?

Comment: @user2864740 - That seems to produce the correct output.  I thought that my regex as constructed had something wrong, but do you know why it behaved that oddly?  Thanks, I will continue testing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that the elements of your regex (unless the matches are at the start/end of the string) require at least one space before and after the match:

```
(^| +?)SOUTH($| +?)
```

matches a space, then `SOUTH`, then another space. Now if the next potential match starts right after that, there would have to be a *second* space character to start the next match. But you only have single spaces between words, so at most every other word can match.

You can visualize this [here](http://regex101.com/r/aW6oY4), for example.

If your goal is to only match entire words instead of substrings, use `\b` [word boundary anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html). `\bSOUTH\b` will match `SOUTH` but not `SOUTHERN`.

Comment: I will experiment with the word boundary anchors.  One of my goals is to replace 3 separate RegEx's with a single one.  So if I had three different regexes:  '^SOUTH ' and ' SOUTH ' and ' SOUTH$', how would I accomplish that?  (Single quotes only for comment)

Comment: @ChrisDunaway: `\bSOUTH\b` will take care of all three. Try `\b(SOUTH|NORTH|WEST|EAST|S|N|W|E)\b` - that covers all the cases.